# OData .NET Core API - Conditional AutoExpand ($expand)

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, expand

I am developing a .NET Core Web API with OData capabilities.

For some entities, I would like to $expand some properties provided the user has the appropriate permissions.

Therefore, I need to handle this $expand part in the API, without the user having to specifically ask for the nested entities he has access to.

Is there a way to apply the `AutoExpand` attribute conditionally?

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT (Possible solution)**

I created a new class, inherited from `EnableQueryAttribute`, then overrode `public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)`.

In this method, I forge a new query string based on the permissions:

```
public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
{
    // Keep the original query string
    string originalQueryString = queryOptions.Request.QueryString.Value;
    
    // Suppose you can get the permissions as followed
    var lPermissions = this.GetPermissions(); 
    
    // Then create a query string based on it
    string forgedQueryString = this.GenerateQueryString(lPermissions);
    
    // Forge a new ODataQueryOptions
    queryOptions.Request.QueryString = new QueryString(forgedQueryString);

    var oQueryOptions = new ODataQueryOptions(queryOptions.Context, queryOptions.Request);

    var queryEntities = oQueryOptions.ApplyTo(queryable, new ODataQuerySettings()
    {
        PageSize = this.PageSize
    });

    // Reset the initial URL (to handle "@odata.nextLink")
    queryOptions.Request.QueryString = new QueryString(originalQueryString);

    return queryEntities;

}
```

Comment: How are permissions defined or evaluated. I have done this with URL rewrite, but it was really messy in the end

Comment: Permissions are retrieved in the database. User can call the API with a JWT token. I also ended up doing this... I will edit my post and add what I did. I was hoping there could be a cleaner solution :(